# function template calling other non template member function

Tags: c++, templates

My class is defined in a `dll` and one class which I am introducing the in `dll` has `function template`. This function is calling other member function, but when I write my client code , Visual studio compiler is giving me linking error for the `non-template function.

Here is my `function template` in the `header`

```
void insertMetaInformation(std::string className, char const* typeString, void* pProperty);

template <typename CLASS, typename T> 
    void RegisterMember(  std::string className, 
      std::string propertyName, 
      std::string realClassName,
      typename MemberProperty<CLASS, T>::GetterType   getFn,        
      typename MemberProperty<CLASS, T>::SetterType   setFn,
      typename MemberProperty<CLASS, int>::LengthType lenFn     = NULL, 
      typename MemberProperty<CLASS, T>::ElemLenType  elemLenFn = NULL )
    {
      MemberProperty<CLASS, T>* pProperty = new MemberProperty<CLASS, T>();
      pProperty->m_getterFn               = getFn;
      pProperty->m_setterFn               = setFn;
      pProperty->m_lenFn                  = lenFn;
      pProperty->m_elementLenFn           = elemLenFn;
      pProperty->m_propertyName           = propertyName;
      pProperty->m_realClassName          = realClassName;

      char const *typeString = ToString<T>::value();

      insertMetaInformation(className, typeString, static_cast<void*>(pProperty));
    }
```

I have implemented `insertMetaInformation` in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: Have you added the source file to the project? Have you tried a "rebuild all"?

Comment: yes, tried with clean build also

Comment: Goto the call location in this template function body, highlight `insertMetaInformation`, press F12. and see where it takes you. If it takes you to the decl above this template, than VS has no idea where the implementation is, and likely one way or another it is not being brought into your project correctly. That could be due to a number of things (the def in the source file doesn't match this prototype, its hidden in a namespace, etc).

Comment: @WhozCraig: it is taking me to the `.cpp` file where `insertMetaInformation` is defined

Comment: @Avinash then there is no simple reason it should not be in your link unless that source file is not being compiled. The IDE resolver is a helluvalot pickier than the linker actually is, hard as that is to believe.

Comment: Is insertMetaInformation correctly exported from DLL? Did you link in import library for the DLL? Does the declaration above match your definition exactly? Have you build both main program and DLL for the same architecture (x86/x64)? Have you used the same calling conventions for both main program and DLL?